# Updating text in XML file using a certain node (Shell script)shell

Tags: xml, shell, sed

Looking for a way to change the values of node in an xml file using shell.

Example of data in xml file:

```
<property>

<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>

<value>jdbc:postgresql://myhost/metastore</value>

</property>
```

Based on `<name>` node, change the text in `<value>` node. Is it achievable through sed or xmlstarlet.

What I want is like based on `<name>` = javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL, change `<value>` to Banana, so the output would be:

```
<property>

    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>

    <value>Banana</value>

 </property>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `xmlstarlet` you can achieve this using the following command:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//property[name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL"]/value' -v newValue source.xml
```

This sets the new value `newValue` in the XML of `source.xml`.

**Additional info:**
Always use an XML parser to process XML files and **not** text-based utilities like `sed`.